# laravel and jwt: always return Unauthorized

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, jwt

I want to use JWT to login in my API but it always give me 
error: "Unauthorized".

Before this, i already register the email and password of the user in my database before trying to login

here's my code :

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => 'login']);
    }

    public function login(Request $request) {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|max:255',
        ]);

        if($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'error',
                'messages' => $validator->messages()
            ], 200);
        }

        if (! $token = auth()->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }

        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
    }

    protected function respondWithToken($token) {
        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => Auth::guard()->factory()->getTTL() * 60
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the guard to be used during authentication.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard
     */

    public function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard('api');
    }
```

here's my guard and default in config/auth.php :

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],

'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'api',
        'passwords' => 'users',
   ],
```

here's my frontend using VueJs that does the login :

```
axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/login', loginData)
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response)
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    commit('loginStop', error.response.data.error);
                    commit('updateAccessToken', null);
                    console.log(error.response);
                })
```

here's my web.php :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function() {
    Route::post('/register', 'UserController@register');
    Route::post('/login', 'UserController@login');
});
```

Here's my output of `php artisan route:list` :
[image: php artisan route:list]

Comment: Are you passing the token upon your request in the Authentication header? Does your request also have the Accept: application/json header?

Comment: @mdexp i'm not using postman

Comment: If so can you post the relevant code that's making the request to your backend?

Comment: @mdexp I've posted it. It's just simple request using axios

Comment: Did you register the user manually into the database?

Comment: @mdexp Yes, i put it manually

Comment: Did you hash the password with your current hashing method that your application is using? (default is bcrypt)

Comment: @mdexp you can see my route list now. And i also don't hash my password

Comment: I think you have to hash the password as Auth::attempt check if the provided password would match the hashed and stored one in the database. If you register your user manually you can hook up a tinker interactive shell with `php artisan tinker` then user Hash::make('yourpassword') to generate an hashed password using the setted Laravel's password hashing system (defaults to bcrypt) and then copy the output string into your database. The login should work then

Comment: Thank you sir, you've saved me

Comment: Glad it worked! I posted an answer so you can mark the question as solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments, you aren't hashing the password of the user that you inserted in the database.

But you have to do it as `Auth::attempt` checks if the provided password would match the hash stored in the database.

If you still want to register the user manually, you can hook up a tinker interactive shell with `php artisan tinker` command and then user `Hash::make('yourpassword')` to generate an hashed password using the setted Laravel's password hashing system (defaults to bcrypt).

Then you just have to copy the output string into your database. The login should finally work as the Auth guard now can check the user input agains a correct database user with a proper hashed password.

Comment: thnks that was exactly my problem, was using a database which was not generated via laravel

Answer (score 1):

I had a totally different issue.
The `auth()->attempt` method was not comparing the password to my `User` model password for some reason.
After adding the following to my `User` model:

```
public function getAuthPassword() {
    return $this->password;
}
```

Everything worked like a charm

Answer (score -1):

The same problem to me, I solved by:

1. Use tinker to generate user credentials, email and password
2. content type in Headers:  `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`